# Seaborn time series plot multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot a time series for the data below. Any ideas on how to accomplish this. tsplot is not available in seaborn. I am trying to show a bar for each "deaths_regiment_" for every day

```
data = {'date': ['2014-05-01', '2014-05-02 ', '2014-05-03', '2014-05-04', '2014-05-05', '2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10'], 
        'deaths_regiment_1': [34, 43, 14, 15, 15, 14, 31, 25, 62, 41],
        'deaths_regiment_2': [52, 66, 78, 15, 15, 5, 25, 25, 86, 1],
        'deaths_regiment_3': [13, 73, 82, 58, 52, 87, 26, 5, 56, 75],
        'deaths_regiment_4': [44, 75, 26, 15, 15, 14, 54, 25, 24, 72],
        'deaths_regiment_5': [25, 24, 25, 15, 57, 68, 21, 27, 62, 5],
        'deaths_regiment_6': [84, 84, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 24],
        'deaths_regiment_7': [46, 57, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 41]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'battle_deaths', 'deaths_regiment_1', 'deaths_regiment_2',
                                   'deaths_regiment_3', 'deaths_regiment_4', 'deaths_regiment_5',
                                   'deaths_regiment_6', 'deaths_regiment_7'])
df = df.set_index(df.date)
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be one more column battle_deaths, I removed it, and set date as `DatetimeIndex` and set that as index. You can just call matplotlib to plot.. because you have a lot of lines, I used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot) to place the legend beside:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'deaths_regiment_1', 'deaths_regiment_2',
                                   'deaths_regiment_3', 'deaths_regiment_4', 'deaths_regiment_5',
                                   'deaths_regiment_6', 'deaths_regiment_7'])

df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
df.plot(ax=ax)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]